# Sorting in a Pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pivot-table, reindex

I have been looking all over trying to figure out how to sort my pivot table correctly and I haven't had any luck.

```
    client          unit    task                hours   month
0   A               DVADA   Account Management  6.50    January     
1   A               DVADA   Buying              1.25    January 
2   A               DVADA   Meeting / Call      0.50    January 
3   A               DVADA   Account Management  3.00    January 
4   A               DVADA   Billing             2.50    February    
5   A               DVADA   Account Management  6.50    February        
6   A               DVADA   Buying              1.25    February    
7   A               DVADA   Meeting / Call      0.50    February    
8   A               DVADA   Account Management  3.00    February    
9   A               DVADA   Billing             2.50    February
10  A               DVADA   Billing             2.50    December    
11  A               DVADA   Account Management  6.50    December        
12  A               DVADA   Buying              1.25    December    
13  A               DVADA   Meeting / Call      0.50    December    
14  A               DVADA   Account Management  3.00    December    
15  A               DVADA   Billing             2.50    December
16  A               DVADA   Account Management  6.50    August      
17  A               DVADA   Buying              1.25    August  
18  A               DVADA   Meeting / Call      0.50    August  
19  A               DVADA   Account Management  3.00    August
20  A               DVADA   Account Management  6.50    April       
21  A               DVADA   Buying              1.25    April   
22  A               DVADA   Meeting / Call      0.50    April   
23  A               DVADA   Account Management  3.00    April
24  B               DVADA   Account Management  6.50    January     
25  B               DVADA   Buying              1.25    January 
26  B               DVADA   Meeting / Call      0.50    January 
27  B               DVADA   Account Management  3.00    January 
28  B               DVADA   Billing             2.50    February    
29  B               DVADA   Account Management  6.50    February        
30  B               DVADA   Buying              1.25    February    
31  B               DVADA   Meeting / Call      0.50    February    
32  B               DVADA   Account Management  3.00    February    
33  B               DVADA   Billing             2.50    February
34  B               DVADA   Billing             2.50    December    
35  B               DVADA   Account Management  6.50    December        
36  B               DVADA   Buying              1.25    December    
37  B               DVADA   Meeting / Call      0.50    December    
38  B               DVADA   Account Management  3.00    December    
39  B               DVADA   Billing             2.50    December
40  B               DVADA   Account Management  6.50    August      
41  B               DVADA   Buying              1.25    August  
42  B               DVADA   Meeting / Call      0.50    August  
43  B               DVADA   Account Management  3.00    August
44  B               DVADA   Account Management  6.50    April       
45  B               DVADA   Buying              1.25    April   
46  B               DVADA   Meeting / Call      0.50    April   
47  C               DVADA   Account Management  3.00    April
48  C               DVADA   Account Management  6.50    January     
49  C               DVADA   Buying              1.25    January 
50  C               DVADA   Meeting / Call      0.50    January 
51  C               DVADA   Account Management  3.00    January 
52  C               DVADA   Billing             2.50    February    
53  C               DVADA   Account Management  6.50    February        
54  C               DVADA   Buying              1.25    February    
55  C               DVADA   Meeting / Call      0.50    February    
56  C               DVADA   Account Management  3.00    February    
57  C               DVADA   Billing             2.50    February
58  C               DVADA   Billing             2.50    December    
59  C               DVADA   Account Management  6.50    December        
60  C               DVADA   Buying              1.25    December    
61  C               DVADA   Meeting / Call      0.50    December    
62  C               DVADA   Account Management  3.00    December    
63  C               DVADA   Billing             2.50    December
64  C               DVADA   Account Management  6.50    August      
65  C               DVADA   Buying              1.25    August  
66  C               DVADA   Meeting / Call      0.50    August  
67  C               DVADA   Account Management  3.00    August
68  C               DVADA   Account Management  6.50    April       
69  C               DVADA   Buying              1.25    April   
70  C               DVADA   Meeting / Call      0.50    April   
71  C               DVADA   Account Management  3.00    April
```

df = pd.pivot_table(vp_clients, values='hours', index=['client', 'month'], aggfunc=sum)

Which returns a pivot table with three columns (client, month, hours). Each client has 12 months (Jan-Dec) and each of those months has a hours for that month.

```
                        hours
client          month

A               April   203.50
                August  227.75
                December 159.75
                February 203.25
                January 199.25

B               April   203.50
                August  227.75
                December 159.75
                February 203.25
                January 199.25

C               April   203.50
                August  227.75
                December 159.75
                February 203.25
                January 199.25
```

I want to sort this pivot table by the months but keep the client column in tacked.

```
                           hours
client           month

A               January 203.50
                February 227.75
                March    159.75
                April    203.25
                May     199.90

B               January 203.50
                February 227.75
                March    159.75
                April    203.25
                May     199.90

C               January 203.50
                February 227.75
                March    159.75
                April    203.25
                May     199.90
```

**The sorting issue is fixed with the answer below from Scott. Now I want to add a row to each client with the total hours used.**

```
                           hours
client           month

A               January    203.50
                February   227.75
                March      159.75
                April      203.25
                May        199.90
                Total     1000.34

B               January    203.50
                February   227.75
                March      159.75
                April      203.25
                May       199.90
                Total     1000.34

C               January   203.50
                February   227.75
                March      159.75
                April      203.25
                May       199.90
                Total     1000.34
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please show us your data and output. It's odd to use `pivot_table` without *columns*. Just use `groupby` instead.

Comment: I do have columns in my data @Parfait

Comment: I meant columns argument of [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html). You are not pivoting anything, only summarizing. Use `groupby`.

Comment: I would recommend converting month to and ordered categorical dtype then using sort_values by client, month.  With more complete data, the SO community could replicate.

Comment: @Parfait, I will try `groupby`, thanks!

Comment: @ScottBoston, Gotcha, I can try to as well. I would put more complete data out for the SO community but I can't provide the fully complete data for security reasons

Comment: Make up some data.  Help us, help you. :)

Comment: @ScottBoston, Good idea! :) I will make some up for you guys

Comment: @ScottBoston, Let me know if this is what you were looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update to add Total at end of each client

```
vp_clients['month'] = pd.Categorical(vp_clients['month'], 
                                     ordered=True, 
                                     categories=['January','February','March',
                                                 'April','May','June','July',
                                                 'August','September','October',
                                                 'November','December','Total'])

df = pd.pivot_table(vp_clients, values='hours', index=['client', 'month'], aggfunc=sum)

df = df.dropna()

pd.concat([df,df.sum(level=0).assign(month='Total').set_index('month', append=True)]).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
                 hours
client month          
A      January   11.25
       February  16.25
       April     11.25
       August    11.25
       December  16.25
       Total     66.25
B      January   11.25
       February  16.25
       April      8.25
       August    11.25
       December  16.25
       Total     63.25
C      January   11.25
       February  16.25
       April     14.25
       August    11.25
       December  16.25
       Total     69.25
```

---

Let's use `pd.Categorical`:

```
vp_clients['month'] = pd.Categorical(vp_clients['month'], 
                                     ordered=True, 
                                     categories=['January','February','March',
                                                 'April','May','June','July',
                                                 'August','September','October',
                                                 'November','December'])

df = pd.pivot_table(vp_clients, values='hours', index=['client', 'month'], aggfunc=sum)

df.dropna()
```

Output:

```
                 hours
client month          
A      January   11.25
       February  16.25
       April     11.25
       August    11.25
       December  16.25
B      January   11.25
       February  16.25
       April      8.25
       August    11.25
       December  16.25
C      January   11.25
       February  16.25
       April     14.25
       August    11.25
       December  16.25
```

Comment: Worked!! Thanks so much!!:)

Comment: That is one way another way  is to turn those month into a datetime dtype and let datetime sort the result for you.

Comment: Happy coding. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how I would go about adding a row called 'Total' at the end of each client that is a sum of the hours??

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, as commented, since you are not pivoting values to new columns in a wide format, consider simply using `groupby()`. And re-consider `reindex()` for custom January-December order, specifying the *level* and interfacing with python's built-in `calendar` module.

```
import calendar
...

grp_df = df.groupby(['client', 'month']).agg({'hours': 'sum'})\
           .reindex(level=1, labels=calendar.month_name)

#                  hours
# client month          
# A      January   11.25
#        February  16.25
#        April     11.25
#        August    11.25
#        December  16.25
# B      January   11.25
#        February  16.25
#        April      8.25
#        August    11.25
#        December  16.25
# C      January   11.25
#        February  16.25
#        April     14.25
#        August    11.25
#        December  16.25
```