# How to modify the following dataframe using groupby/pivot?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot

I have the following pandas dataframe:
[image]

I want to change this dataframe in the following way:
I want to have the ID column as index and the month for each index in a column named month, and then all the values as follow:

```
ID    MONTH  VAL
1     Jan    nan
1     Feb    nan
1     Mar    nan
1     Apr    nan
1     May    nan
1     Jun    nan
1     Jul    nan
1     Aug    94.0000
1     Sep    113.0000
1     Oct    21.0000
1     Nov    nan
2     Jan    107.00000
.
.
.
7     Nov    nan
```

The order of the month is not important. Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Instead of posting a picture, can you post output from `df.head(10).to_dict()`. This will help us test solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `stack` with `dropna`parameter set to False:

```
df.set_index('ID').stack(dropna=False)
```

@PaulH is correct in his observations from the comments below.

To move that column index to row index converting from a wide dataframe to a long dataframe.

Comment: I think you'll need to set the index on the `'ID'` column first

Comment: you'll need to "categorize" the remaining column to them to sort properly

Comment: OP states that order is not important.

Comment: Ok i understood the first part, but  didn't understand  the part in which i have to convert from a wide dataframe to a long. Because after the stack i obtain a Series

Comment: @MarcoMiglionico that was just the way the dataframe looks.  it was just a statement.  Not import to the solution.

Comment: If order of month is important this see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48916148/6361531)

Comment: @ScottBoston oh yes i see that. oops.

Comment: @ScottBoston I used df.melt() after the stack to have the dataset exactly as in the code i posted. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, melt is a great method also.  Probably faster.  You're welcome.  Happy coding!